# KSH syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".111111111 -2.55555")

Tags: command-line, calculator, ksh

I have the following example, and I cannot see why.

```
 line 48: 15.111111111 -2.55555: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".111111111 -2.55555")
```

This is my source in ksh:

```
export a=2.55555
export b=15.111111111
export c=$(( $b -$a))
echo $c
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Comment: following error*

Comment: Put each export on it's own line, and the echo too.

Comment: Please show us exactly how you are executing the script. Does it have a `ksh` shebang? Most likely you are actually running the code with a different shell, such as `bash` or `dash` (`sh`) that does not support non-integer arithmetic.

Comment: `export c=$(echo "$b-$a" | bc)` should work (if `bc` is installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is valid *in ksh* (although it is not necessary to `export` the variables, unless you plan on using them in a child environment). So for example given

```
$ cat myscript.ksh
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

export a=2.55555
export b=15.111111111
export c=$(( $b -$a))
echo $c
```

then

```
chmod +x myscript.ksh

$ ./myscript.ksh
12.555561111
```

**However** most other common shells do not support non-integer arithmetic - based on the error message it looks like you are actually executing the code with `bash`:

```
$ bash ./myscript.ksh
./myscript.ksh: line 5: 15.111111111 -2.55555: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".111111111 -2.55555")
```

Comment: I understand know, thank you very much, it is OK with chmod+x

Answer (score -1):

*ksh has floating point support, so ksh was not used?*

`Bash` doesn't do decimals in `$(( ... ))`,
i.e. floating point numbers cannot be used.

One can look up the relevant section in `man bash` -manual by typing
`/^ARITH` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Well there you will see:
"Evaluation  is  done in fixed-width **integers** with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error."

---

As @Terrance says in a comment above:
`export c=$(echo "$b - $a | bc)` should work.

Comment: ksh does have floating-point numbers.

Comment: Well, then - updated.